# MySQL - UPDATE one column's values using one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have this db table:

```
Items
-------
id  // values: 1,2,3,4,5 ... 
name // values: Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4,Item5 ...
order // values: 1, 5, 2, 3, 4 ...
```

The items are images. The image order is set in an array when dragging the images around, but in order to update the order, I use one UPDATE inside a loop. I was wondering if I could do the UPDATE without using a loop.

I was wondering if I can update the item's order at once, using only one UPDATE query.

Comment: Depends what you want the value of `order` to be. If they're just supposed to be the same as the `id` you can do `UPDATE Items SET order = id` but I doubt thats what you want. Please clarify.

Comment: The items are images. The image order is set in an array when dragging the images around, but in order to update the order, I use one UPDATE inside a loop. I was wondering if I could do the UPDATE without using a loop.

Comment: The order will be updated to the new order set. Please review the post, I did an edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT (..) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (..)` syntax.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `order`)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `order` = VALUES(`order`)
```